# Is it possible to have the browser read gzipped data if Content-Encoding: gzip is not specified?

Tags: javascript, browser, http-headers, gzip, unzip

I'm playing around with fetching manually gzipped files from a static file server.

My problem is once I'm not including the `Content-Encoding: gzip` header in my response, the browser does not recognize content as being gzipped.

**Question:**
The header is there for a reason, but I'm still wondering whether there are any ways to have the browser (not Javascript) handle a gzipped resource?

Thanks for some pointers! Haven't found any...

Comment: no, unfortunately the browser listens to the server about that header.

Comment: mh. Thought so. Still want to wait a bit, but can you post an answer, so I can check? Thanks!

Comment: actually, i thought of something that MAY work; you can use binary ajax to grab the url, and then use a JS-based inflate routine to un-compress the data. i know inflate is avail as a lib, not sure about bzip...

Comment: ah, this sounds explorable...